# Google Maps API JS V3: infowindow.getPosition() == undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wanted to make something to toogle if the infowindow is visable. My expression is:

```
    if(infowindow.getPosition() != marker.getPosition())
```

The porblem is, that infowindow.getPosition() returns undefined, also if it has a position.
[JSFiddle-Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5yj2a/)

What did I do wrong?

Full Code:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                    html,body,#map-canvas {
                        height: 100%;
                        width:100%;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                    }
                </style>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=de&v=3"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $( document ).ready(function() {
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.2881829, 11.4835767),
                            zoom: 6
                        });

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.2881829, 11.4835767),
                            map: map,
                        });

                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: '<div id="content">test123</div>'
                        });

                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                            console.log(infowindow.getPosition());
                            console.log(marker.getPosition());
                            if(infowindow.getPosition() != marker.getPosition()) {
                                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                            } else {
                                infowindow.close();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems the `open`-method doesn't update the `position` of the `infowindow`, you'll need to do it on your own(e.g. by binding the position of the infowindow to the position of the marker):

```
    infowindow.unbind('position');
    if(infowindow.getPosition() != this.getPosition()) {
        infowindow.bindTo('position',this,'position');
        infowindow.open(map,this);
    } else {           
        infowindow.close();
        infowindow.setPosition(null);
    }
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/aBg3N/**](http://jsfiddle.net/aBg3N/)

Another solution(but this solution relies on a undocumented property `anchor`):

```
    if(infowindow.get('anchor') != this) {
        infowindow.open(map,this);
    } else {
        infowindow.close();
    }
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/AZC3z/**](http://jsfiddle.net/AZC3z/)

Both solutions will work with draggable markers and also when you use the same infowindow for multiple markers

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `infowindow.getPosition()` . But you can try this code if you want to check whether the infowindow is open or not.

JS:

```
function check(infoWindow) {
    var map = infoWindow.getMap();
    return (map !== null && typeof map !== "undefined");
}
```

pass `infowindow` into the function and it will return `true` or `false` based on visibility of `infowindow`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x8dSP/3699/

Comment: Only for testing, I have one marker. With more than one markers, that wouldn't do the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the google.maps.InfoWindow won't have a position unless you set one, if I do this:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div id="content">test</div>',
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0)
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yj2a/25/)

or:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div id="content">test</div>',
    position: marker.getPosition()
});
```

`infowindow.getPosition()` returns the value set.

Unfortunately, that can't be used to detect whether or not the infowindow is currently visible or not, so your test won't work as expected.